# Why debug works when I delete .git directory? [Build error AWS Toolkit + AWS SAM]

Tags: aws-lambda, build, aws-sam, goland, aws-toolkit

I'm facing an unusual issue. I am able to debug lambdas with AWS toolkit + Goland using SAM, this is working perfectly. But in a specific case I'm having an error in the BUILD related to VCS. After several tests I concluded that the problem was the .git directory, because when I deleted it the build worked and the debug too. I tried to invalidate caches through Goland but it didn't work. What would be the relationship of this .git directory with this error in the build?

[image]

I tried several plugin settings, as they didn't work I tried a very simple test that worked, so I figured the problem must be in some file in the project directory and by elimination I got to the .git directory.

**Edit** An additional explanation: The problem is the .git directory. It doesn't matter if it has the files generated by git or if it is empty, it is enough for the directory to exist for the problem to occur.

Comment: I believe that you should add `-buildvcs=falses` to run configuration settings (_Run | Edit Configurations_) in something like arguments or environment fields.

Comment: I did that but it didn't work